# How do i remove dots at the end of Row data in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

whenever I am trying to get any data from a Pandas Dataframe, using the index, it is giving me data with dots at the end, the data is long but the output is coming with dots at the end.

```
                                                  0
1   fsfsfsf         | himanshu@gmail.com    | o&9na+%06STLZp&TE   
2   r25t4e ukiki    | himanshu@gmail.com    | z96FIt+H43...       
3   juikyu7otjurfyh | himanshu@gmail.com    | NtOb%z0...          
4   dqadd           | himanshu@gmail.com    | adadada             
5   rfw3tgegtegt    | himanshu@gmail.com    | 27K(qfkm5)...       
6   wwwr            | himanshu@gmail.com    | cfbZih&)0X&i91      
7   eewftg          | himanshu@gmail.com    | XV8#huq9K%Z2#Jd8R   
8   rerer           | himanshu@gmail.com    | 8i9vi!(sf!BAf57Fi   
9   dadadad         | himanshu@gmail.com    | dadadada            
10  Amazon          | himanshu@gmail.com    | iS3FSy)Lu+3c%hY
```

Answer (score 0):

To remote trailing dots, we can use `str.rstrip`:

```py
df["your_col"] = df["your_col"].str.rstrip('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Data

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fsfsfsf | himanshu@gmail.com | o&9na+%06STLZp&TE |
| 2 | r25t4e ukiki | himanshu@gmail.com | z96FIt+H43... |
| 3 | juikyu7otjurfyh | himanshu@gmail.com | NtOb%z0... |
| 4 | dqadd | himanshu@gmail.com | adadada |
| 5 | rfw3tgegtegt | himanshu@gmail.com | 27K(qfkm5)... |
| 6 | wwwr | himanshu@gmail.com | cfbZih&)0X&i91 |
| 7 | eewftg | himanshu@gmail.com | XV8#huq9K%Z2#Jd8R |
| 8 | rerer | himanshu@gmail.com | 8i9vi!(sf!BAf57Fi |
| 9 | dadadad | himanshu@gmail.com | dadadada |
| 10 | Amazon | himanshu@gmail.com | iS3FSy)Lu+3c%hY |

### Explain

The `...` is not a bug for output, it is just display optimization.

For example.

```py
Df({"a":["0"*80]})
```

You will see

```
                                                   a
0  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
```

### Answer

If you want to check what the data exactly, try `df.to_csv` or other method.